# AngularJS is not recognizing JSON from PHPMailer

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm having troubles getting AngularJS to recognize that my PHPMailer sent correctly. It's returning the success json according to the console but it's not populating the proper classes on my page, which leads me to believe that the .success function is being called, but for some reason it's triggering the else statement. I have a call setup in a controller like so:

```
  .controller('ContactCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.result = 'hidden'
    $scope.resultMessage;
    $scope.formData; //formData is an object holding the name, email, subject, and message
    $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
    $scope.submitted = false; //used so that form errors are shown only after the form has been submitted
    $scope.submit = function(contactform) {
        $scope.submitted = true;
        $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
        if (contactform.$valid) {
            $http({
                method  : 'POST',
                url     : 'contact-form.php',
                data    : $.param($scope.formData),  //param method from jQuery
                headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  //set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
            }).success(function(data){
                console.log(data);
                if (data.success) { //success comes from the return json object
                    $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
                    $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
                    $scope.result='bg-success';
                } else {
                    $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
                    $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
                    $scope.result='bg-danger';
                }
            });
        } else {
            $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
            $scope.resultMessage = 'Failed.';
            $scope.result='bg-danger';
        }
    }
});
```

Whenever I look in the console I'm seeing that my PHP script is returning JSON indicating that it worked (It logs under .success). However when I use ng-binding class in my markup it's triggering the class declared in the else statement, and it's not populating the page with the message either.

```
{"success":true,"message":"Thanks! We have received your message."}


<div ng-controller="ContactCtrl" class="panel-body ng-scope">
    <form ng-submit="submit(contactform)" name="contactform" class="form-horizontal ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" role="form">
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputName.$invalid &amp;&amp; submitted }">
            <label for="inputName" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input ng-model="formData.inputName" type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" id="inputName" name="inputName" placeholder="Your Name" required="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputEmail.$invalid &amp;&amp; submitted }">
            <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input ng-model="formData.inputEmail" type="email" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-email" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" placeholder="Your Email" required="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputSubject.$invalid &amp;&amp; submitted }">
            <label for="inputSubject" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Subject</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input ng-model="formData.inputSubject" type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" id="inputSubject" name="inputSubject" placeholder="Subject Message" required="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputMessage.$invalid &amp;&amp; submitted }">
            <label for="inputMessage" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Message</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <textarea ng-model="formData.inputMessage" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" rows="4" id="inputMessage" name="inputMessage" placeholder="Your message..." required=""></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="submitButtonDisabled">
                    Send Message
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <p ng-class="result" style="padding: 15px; margin: 0;" class="ng-binding hidden"></p>
</div>
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: what is being returned?

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry, it got muddled with the markup. {"success":true,"message":"Thanks! We have received your message."}

Comment: where are you using {{ resultMessage }} in your HTML? can not see it.

Comment: Not sure about angular, but try using realData = JSON.parse(data);

Comment: @charlietfl It does not have the quotations, my apologies.  I wrapped that to indicate what it's returning.

Comment: @Dodekeract angular is using its own parse after http request, so it will return object automatically, but you can use angular-way parsing  `angular.fromJson()` or `angular.toJson()`

Comment: I'm unsure why I would need to process the Json if it's returning valid Json?  {"success":true,"message":"Thanks! We have received your message."}

Comment: The `.success` function is not checking for valid JSON, only for an HTTP 200-300 code.

If the result is detected as valid JSON, it's automatically transformed into an object. See the section, Default Transformations  here.  
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: I just managed to solve this as I was reading your reply. I had SMTPDebug turned on within PHPMailer and it wasn't returning properly. Setting it to false corrected it, hooray.